# Name of book with a planet with one alien left alive?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

What is the name of the short SF work in which there is one alien left alive on a planet which humans are working (mining maybe).  The planet is described quite bleakly but when described as seen through the aliens eyes it is quite a different place.  What is the name and who is the author of that book?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds vaguely like ["Alone"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1148296) by Robert Reed.

It featured an alien, the only one of its kind who hides and observes humans undertaking a variety of activities including surface repair and digging.

There's a brief synopsis [here](http://tentoinfinity.com/2012/12/19/alone-by-robert-reed/);

> *"The story being told feels epic as well, even though the main
> character, the walker, just wants to be left alone. It feels little
> interest in conversing or even being noticed by the increasingly
> prevalent humans. One of the nice features of the story is sense of
> the wider world, that beyond the walker there are vast migrations and
> colonisations across the Great Ship. And while the walker has this
> strong, easily relatable desire for solitude, the reader never forgets
> that this is an other; it works on far vaster timescales, and thinks
> nothing of standing still for a few decades when something scares it."*

Comment: The book - it was short, so i'm not sure if we call it a novel, novella or novelette!  i read it about 15 or so year ago and I think it had been written maybe in the 5 or 10 years before that.  It wasn't robert reed's alone.  The alien i think was not very humanoid and since the alien and the human could not communicate the alien was treated more as an animal to be eradicated.  i think the title have a worD similar to 'celestial' in it but an internet search doesn't bring it up.

Comment: Coelestial something...maybe

Comment: @user14111 - Done, sorted

Comment: Yes, i answered some of those question you asked but I still have not found the title and author of the work :(

Comment: @Suvajra - Unfortunately some YASID questions go unsolved for week, months and years, especially when the description is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

A possible match is *Terminal Quest* (also published under the title *The Last Monster*), a short story by Poul Anderson.  According to [this review of the story](http://poulandersonappreciation.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/terminal-quest.html) the majority of the story is shown from the viewpoint of the last remaining native to the world which is in the process of being colonized by humans.  However, the descriptions given of the world are reversed from what you remember: the viewpoint of the native (as I recall; this isn't mentioned in the review and I don't have a copy of the story myself at present) is that the world is bleak while the viewpoint (presumably from a human perspective) shown after he has died shows the world as a somewhat idyllic place.